# Using a form to edit an existing field in a custom list

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to add a form that only updates a field in one column. I am having a dickens of a time finding information on that. Quick edit works great, but my team wants it to be even easier. Can anyone provide info or point me to a resource?

Kelly

Comment: I would say custom code is the only viable option for "even easier". Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: that's the conclusion I have come to as well. I'm using SharePoint 2013

Comment: If you have someone who can do some coding jslink for the column would work. In SharePoint Online Moder UI I would teach the users to use the "info pane" to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an InfoPath form with [a repeating table](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/insert-a-repeating-table-e313db25-fbd6-4dcd-b874-60c0b377c574).

Then, you can add rows of data from a Repeating Table to a SharePoint list by submitting a CAML update batch to the UpdateListItems method of the Lists web service.

Refer to detailed steps in this article: [How to update a SharePoint list via an InfoPath browser form using the SharePoint Object Model](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-submit-items-rows-repeating-table-infopath-sharepoint-list.htm)